# IEnumerable<T>: Can use Equals method but not equality operator

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, equality-operator

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable){

    T previous = default(T);
    foreach(T current in iterable){

        if (!current.Equals(previous)){

            previous = current;
            yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any questions about this code, but just why if it is possible to compare two objects of type T using:

```
if (!current.Equals(previous))
```

Then why is it not possible to compare using:

```
if (!current == previous)
```

The ! gives you an error saying

> Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'T'

And if you remove that you get:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

I gave up on a code challenge because it seemed to be telling me you literally can't compare one T to another. Then I found out you can do that but just with different syntax/using a specific method.

Can anyone advise why this would be please?

Comment: What kind of "why" are you looking for? That's just how the language is designed? Would you be satisfied with a quote from the language specification? See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819

Comment: I'm satisfied with the answer below. At this stage I'm just learning how all the parts of the language fit together and so my "why" questions may be easily answered.

Comment: In that case, you should consider accepting an answer by clicking on that checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1211-relational-and-type-testing-operators) of the language specification where `==` is specified. You can see that the language only has these overloads of `==` predefined:

```
bool operator ==(int x, int y);
bool operator ==(uint x, uint y);
bool operator ==(long x, long y);
bool operator ==(ulong x, ulong y);
bool operator ==(float x, float y);
bool operator ==(double x, double y);
bool operator ==(decimal x, decimal y);
bool operator ==(bool x, bool y);
bool operator ==(E x, E y); // for every enum E
bool operator ==(C x, C y); // for every class C
bool operator ==(string x, string y);
bool operator ==(System.Delegate x, System.Delegate y);
```

The type parameter `T` in your method is not constrained to anything, so what if it is, for example, a struct type? As you can see from the above list, there are no `==` operators defined for an arbitrary struct type.

If you add a `T: class` constraint, then you would be able to use `==` on it, because there is a `==` operator for all classes.

On the other hand, there is an [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0) method declared in `System.Object`, from which every type in C# inherits from. Therefore, it is possible to use `Equals` on values of type `T`, even when `T` can be any type.

Comment: Thanks man, really helpful. I will mark your answer as accepted only because it's a bit more detailed. Both were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`.Equals` is a part of `System.Object`. Right now there is no way to constrain a generic to have support for a specific operator overloading. You can however use `IEquatable<T>` or `IEqualityComparer<T>` to ensure the type implements its definition of equality.

Comment: So I'm thinking of the equality operator as being available globally where actually it has to be implemented for each particular type. That being the case it makes sense that you can't implement an operator for a type (T) that isn't actually a type.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `==` can only mean value equality if the object is a primitive value type, a string, or a user struct with the `operator ==` defined.

In all other cases, `==` is either not defined (value types) or refers to `object.ReferenceEquals()` that checks if both variables refer to the same object in memory.

Note that the new `record` types support the `==` operator with value semantics even though they are reference types. This is because behind the scenes they implement `IEquatable<T>` and define `operator ==` to use `.Equals()`.